# Mongodb equivalent for Mysql DATE_ADD?

Tags: mongodb

Is there an equivalent in Mongodb for Mysql's DATE_ADD() function?

Answer (score 2):

This currently isn't possible. There is a feature request for allowing the "$inc" modifier to be used on Dates in MongoDB which will make this possible in future versions.  You can vote for and track the ticket [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3174).

As an alternative, store the date as milliseconds, and use $inc to add to it.

Comment: Just want to document that this applies to the current 2.0.x version